# SequenceJS - Width of step is not 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with 100% width of the step `<li>` tags. I've added the property `width: 100%;` but on mobile screen the `<li>` is like 96% the width of the screen. It only covers the screen if I increase the width to 104% at least. There's no margin or padding anywhere.

There's a lot of css for SequenceJS and I don't know what the cause is so I'm not putting any code here, (apologies) instead I've setup a demo page where you can see the problem

[Demo](http://bwdmedia.in/testbench/webdev/)

Please help me find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `transform: translateX(-40px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px);` inline style which does the problem, also you need to remove the padding for the ul with:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0px; //because by default you have 40px padding left for the ul's
}
```

and then change all the widths of the ul and li's to 100%;

This worked for me.

Comment: Good answer. But block elements like `ul` and `li` don't need an explicit `width`. Resetting the margins and paddings is enough.

Comment: But even if padding goes to 0 and ul and li are 100%, it still wouldn't work right. Why is the starting position of Sequencejs -40px and not 0. Do you know how it's calculating that?

Comment: It might be -40px because the bootstrap ul's has a default padding-left value of 40px. I haven't worked with Sequencejs, I only inspected your website and changed style with my firebug to get the desired result.

Comment: Oh Wait that worked. I was changing padding in the dev tools after the page had loaded. I tried changing it in the css and reloading, and it's calculating properly. Thanks